# Menu table takes up full height of webpage with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I have this table containing links. When pressed, it displays the results on the same page. My problem is that the results go underneath the menu. I want to use CSS to make the table's height take up the whole page.

This is the table:

```
<div id="categories">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Categories</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=apts">Appetizers</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=brds">Breads</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=brek">Breakfast</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=cond">Condiments</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=dsrt">Desserts</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=drnk">Drinks</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=hmed">Homemade Ingredients</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=lnch">Lunch & Snacks</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=main">Main Dishes</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=psre">Pasta & Rice</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=slds">Salads</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=sauc">Sauces & Salsas</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=side">Side Dishes</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=stup">Soups & Stews</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=spcl">Special Diet</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=vegi">Vegitarian</a></br></li>
                    <li><a href="categories.php?c=diet">Weight Watchers</a></br></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

At the moment my CSS has :

```
div#categories{
    float: left;
}
```

I tried giving the `td` an `id` and having `height: 100%;` but that did nothing as well as just giving the table height 100% or px.  Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: I would avoid using tables. Tables should be used for tabular data. You are going to have a hard time getting layouts to work with tables.

Comment: its just for a little side menu which comes out nicely. I want to know how i can make it so the data it retrieves wont go underneath the menu

Comment: Why dont you try bootstrap navs?
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

Comment: Can you please provide a link to a page where we can see the behavior you are describing? Or provide a page on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: The images  break but it gives a good idea of what happens with the posts  http://jsfiddle.net/XhcdB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/XhcdB/

```
div#recipes{
    float: left; 
}

div#pageMiddle{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that inline-block did the job. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are several approaches you could take. Here they are in order of preference:

1. Put all of your main content in a div and float it right. Then your
   nav will float left and the content right. This is the modern best-practice way to do layout.
2. Use an iframe - if you're ok with having an iframe, put your content
   in an iframe on the right. Your nav wouldn't reload with every click and your content in the iframe could scroll, etc.
   Not the ideal solution, but could work.
3. Use tables - You could create a large table that takes up the whole
   page with your nav in the left td and content in the right td. This
   is obviously an older and not-preferred way to do it, but it would
   work.